# Nuxtをnode18以上で、Vercelにデプロイするとエラーが出る。

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, webapi

質問に不慣れで、至らない点があったら申し訳ありません。

現在、ECサイトを運営しています。

フロントはnuxtで制作
バックエンドはShopifyのstorefront APIを使用しています。

以上の構成でVercelにデプロイしているのですが、
nodeのバージョンを18以上にしてデプロイすると以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Cannot add property x-vercel-id, object is not extensible
  at Ce (./___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js:14:6797)  
  at Object.mutateHeaders (./___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js:15:1143)  
  at ./___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js:7:991  
  at ./___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js:14:5517  
  at _optionalChain (./___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js:7:969)  
  at n (./___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js:14:5439)  
  at Proxy.fetch (./chunks/app/server.mjs:1781:32)  
  at Proxy.<anonymous> (./chunks/app/server.mjs:1292:22)  
  at ./chunks/app/server.mjs:1891:54  
  at executeAsync (./chunks/app/server.mjs:474:19)
```

ウェブサイト自体は表示されますが、ShopifyのAPIから500エラーで情報を取ってこれない状態です。
解決策がわかる方がいらっしゃれば、ご教授をいただければ幸いです。

よろしくお願い致します。